# unable to Use jersey specific features in netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: java, rest, jersey, netbeans-7

I am developing an web application using rest web services.
I am using netbeans.
After creating the web application wizards, for creating web service
1. new-> RESTful web service from patterns -> simple root resource
2. after filling class name, package and all details, netbeans has usually option for

```
Use Jersey Specific Feature
```

In my office PC this option is there. I have install the same version of netbeans at home PC, but I am not seeing the above     `Use Jersey Specific feature` option.

I have tried with adding jersey-core-1.13.bundle in the library as found it while googling around, but it didn't work.
I am using netbeans 7.3.1 and JavaEE 7

How should I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this use jersey feature option is coming in specific configurations of jersey/JEE/Netbean. It's referenced as a bug on netbeans. It's well explained in a netbean post. Please take a look at [netbean reference bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=235189)

NETBEAN BUG EXTRACT :

> > It's working as designed. We support REST configuration by using javax.ws.rc.core.Application subclass only.
>
> The "Use Jersey Specific features" panel(section) was removed for
>   JavaEE 7 we applications, or in JavaEE 6 when Jersey 2.0 is detected
>   on classpath.
>
> Thus, the use cases are the following:
>
> 1.JavaEE 7 (JAX-RS 2.0):
>   - javax.ws.rc.core.Application subclass configuration
>
> 1. JavaEE 6 + Jersey 2.0 on classpath  (e.g. GlassFish 4 or Tomcat with Jersey 2.0)
>
>    - javax.ws.rc.core.Application subclass configuration
> 2. JavaEE 6 + Jersey 1.x on classpath (e.g. GlassFish 3.1)
>
>    - javax.ws.rc.core.Application subclass configuration or
>    - Jersey specific configuration using web.xml
>
> Note: this is the only case, when "Use Jersey Specific features" panel
>   is available
>
> 1. JavaEE 5 + Jersey 2.0 on classpath
>
>    - Jersey specific configuration using web.xml
>
> The general approach with REST is to get rid of Jersey specific stuff
>   as most as possible, and use rather JAX-RS only.
>
> Ken, could you please update the tutorial, and remove the "Use Jersey
>   specific features" section (bottom wizard panel in step 5).  Also the
>   next panel in step 5 ("Rest Resources Configuretion" panel) was
>   removed, and is not available anymore.

enjoy :)